# Fabrik8 - Delete only some containers

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, fabric8

I had used the plugin of Fabric8 to orchestrate my images and containers.

Among them, I would only need one of the containers to be erased when I launched the maven (the app); The others containers: RabbitMQ, MySQL, ... that i import directly from the hub, I would not need to stop and erase them if they already had a container with the image running.

For now I used `mvn clean package docker:stop docker:build docker:start` to stop build (only the app) and start all the containers, would anyone know of any property to choose which container is stopped/deleted and which does not?

**UPDATE**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.23.0</version>

    <configuration>
        <!-- <dockerHost>http://192.168.99.100:2375</dockerHost> -->
        <dockerHost>http://127.0.0.1:2375</dockerHost>

        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <images>
            <image>
                <name>${docker.image.name}</name>
                <alias>${docker.alias.name}</alias>
                <build>
                    <dockerFile>Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                    <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/docker/</dockerFileDir>

                    <assembly>
                        <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                    </assembly>

                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                    </tags>
                </build>
                <run>
                    <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                    <ports>
                        <port>
                            8888:8888
                        </port>
                    </ports>
                </run>
            </image>
            <image>
                <name>rabbit-sdk</name>
                <alias>some-rabbit</alias>

                <build>
                    <assembly>
                        <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                    </assembly>
                    <dockerFile>DockerfileRabbit</dockerFile>
                    <dockerFileDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/docker/</dockerFileDir>
                    <tags>
                        <tag>latest</tag>
                    </tags>
                </build>
                <run>
                    <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                    <ports>
                        <port>
                            8181:15672
                        </port>
                        <port>
                            5671:5671
                        </port>
                        <port>
                            5672:5672
                        </port>
                    </ports>
                </run>
            </image>
            <image>
                <name>redis</name>
                <alias>some-redis</alias>
                <run>
                    <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                    <ports>
                        <port>6379:6379</port>
                    </ports>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you provide the maven plugin configuration you are using?

Comment: Sorry the delay i was out of office. I add you the code of my plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The maven plugin [documentation for the docker:stop](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:stop) documents all the available flags for stopping container. In particular, the `keepContainer` system property can be useful:

```
keepContainer

If set to true not destroy container after they have been stopped. Default is false.
```

When this is used, the image containers defined in the pom will be stopped but not removed when invoking the `docker:stop` goal. You can the clean the app container with the [docker:remove](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#docker:remove) goal.

With the `docker:remove` you can specify explicitly which container to delete. In your case the app container:

```
mvn -Ddocker.filter=<app-image-name> docker:remove
```

Thus the complete maven command would be:

```
mvn clean package -Ddocker.keepContainer -Ddocker.filter=<app-image-name> docker:stop docker:remove docker:build docker:start
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Try with the command but give me errors.
I do it with `clean package -Ddocker.keepContainer -Ddocker.filter=some-server docker:stop docker:remove docker:build docker:start` but return me the error `Conflict. The container name "/some-server" is already in use by container "058be8abfdf9ffe3ad2cd0159c00b291b1d268ceabe0cefeefa033bf78258df2". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name. (Conflict: 409)`.
Anyway i think your idea is a good approach, i will continue investigating with your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove a container, you’ll need to pass the option `keepContainer=false` to the `docker:stop`  command. To  remove a specific docker app image, you can use the `removeMode` property with the filter option. It will be like:

```
mvn -Ddocker.filter=<image-name-for-app> docker:remove
```